# UK Visitor Visa application question

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

I was refused a UK visa last year September and I am applying again. I answered yes when I was asked if I have ever been refused a Visa to the UK but I don't understand the next question:

> "Give more details of what happened"

Should I state the EC's decision or reasons as to why I got refused or simply just write because I did not meet the requirements ?

Comment: I would Write the application refusal reference # and a short summary of what I think was the reason of the refusal. They have their own reasons on the record already

Answer (score 2):

From the comments:

> I would Write the application refusal reference # and a short summary of what I think was the reason of the refusal. They have their own reasons on the record already.

I would also write the reasons for refusal. Even though they have all this info, providing it shows you are honest and gives you a higher chance of getting accepted.

Comment: The OP is already being honest by making the disclosure. Instead of just writing the refusal, make sure to highlight how this application overcomes those reasons.